# MySQL query executes fine, but returns (false) empty result set when using != NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following result set, that I'm trying to drill down

```
+----+---------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| id | auth_id | trusts_number | buy_sell_actions_id | corporate_actions_id | fx_actions_id | submitted |    created_at    |    updated_at    |
+----+---------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|  2 |       6 | N100723       | 2                   | NULL                 | NULL          |         0 | 08/05/2015 11:30 | 08/05/2015 15:32 |
|  5 |       6 | N100723       | NULL                | NULL                 | 1             |         0 | 08/05/2015 15:10 | 08/05/2015 15:10 |
|  6 |       6 | N100723       | NULL                | NULL                 | 2             |         1 | 08/05/2015 15:12 | 08/05/2015 15:41 |
+----+---------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

This result set is generated with the query

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE auth_id = 6 AND trusts_number = 'N100723'
```

I also want to get rid of any field with fx_actions is NULL, so I change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE auth_id = 6 AND trusts_number = 'N100723' AND fx_actions_id != NULL
```

However this returns an empty result set. I've never used "negative" query parameters in MySQL before, so I'm not sure if they should take on a different syntax or what?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal comparison operators don't work well with `NULL`. Both `Something = NULL` and `Something != NULL` will return 'unknown', which causes the row to be omitted in the result. Use the special operators `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM actions 
WHERE auth_id = 6 
  AND trusts_number = 'N100723' 
  AND fx_actions_id IS NOT NULL
```

[Wikipedia on NULL and its background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

Answer (score 0):

Because `null` isn't  a value, you should use `IS NOT NULL`